# Prepared Statements in MySQL - Trying to remove a row results in ProgrammingError

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, prepared-statement, mysql-python

I want to use prepared statements to remove a row from a table, but it results in an error: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

Relevant code:

```py
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='user',
    database='web_board',
    password='password',
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)

crs = db.cursor()

# construct the query and remove post from the database
query = 'DELETE FROM posts WHERE postid=%s'
crs.execute(query, tuple(request.data))

db.commit()

crs.close()
db.close()
```

`request.data` looks like this: `b'9b23f24e-ff4d-4113-85ae-ff8a4a5de3be'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html), to use prepared statements, you should instantiate your cursor with following config:

```
crs = db.cursor(prepared=True)
```

Prepared statements executed with MySQLCursorPrepared can use the format (%s) or qmark (?) parameterization style.